# My Favicon isn't showing up on my local server

Tags: favicon

I'm working on a local server and trying to add a simple favicon. I have already searched high and low on these forums, and tried everything. I'm not sure what is going wrong.

This is the code I have inserted into the head of my code:

```
<link href="http://www.canwise.com/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

my favicon image is in the same folder as my html file for this page. I haven't even put it in an images folder.

I can't for the life of my figure out what I'm doing wrong? I'm working with someone else's coded files so the homepage file is not called "index.html" it's called "application.html.erb" does this have anything to do with it? Also, all the other html files are stored in different folders. But I put the favicon image in the same folder as the html.

any suggestions? please help. I'm also new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it will work if you remove the "shortcut" text from your `rel` tag. It should look like this: `rel="icon"` I think the "shortcut" text is proprietary to old IE browsers.

If that doesn't work I would check your paths. Test using a relative path instead of the full path. for example: `href="favicon.ico"` if your icon is in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change the href to point to the favicon - at the moment it points to a favicon on a url but there doesn't seem to be a favicon there.

As an example, if your running a local server rather than opening a file in the browser directly then the following would work (assuming the icon is at the webroot).

```
<link href="/" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
```